# Using JSON path in tabular input data for JSON output schema in an Azure Data Factory flow

Tags: json, sql-server, azure-data-factory

I've seen how to use the Aggregate transformation in an ADF Data Flow along with a **static** hierarchy specified in a Derived Columns transformation and the collect() function to output custom JSON.

What I want to do is a little more dynamic. If my tabular data contains one column with a single attribute value, and another column with a string representing the JSON path to which I want the first column's attribute value to be output in the JSON schema, how would this sort of transformation be achieved?

Table Input:

```sql
CREATE TABLE EAV (EntityID int, AttributePath nvarchar(500), AttributeValue nvarchar(max))

INSERT EAV VALUES
(1, 'user.firstName','John'),
(1, 'user.lastName','Doe'),
(1, 'user.address.city','Pittsburgh'),
(1, 'user.address.state','Pennsylvania'),
(2, 'user.firstName','Jane'),
(2, 'user.lastName','Doe'),
(2, 'user.address.city','Pittsburgh'),
(2, 'user.address.state','Pennsylvania');
```

JSON Output:

```
{
    "user": {
        "id" : 1
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "address": {
            "city": "Pittsburgh",
            "state": "Pennsylvania"
        }
    },
    "user": {
        "id" : 2
        "firstName": "Jane",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "address": {
            "city": "Pittsburgh",
            "state": "Pennsylvania"
        }
    },
}
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server doesn't deal well with dynamic JSON keys. You can use dynamic SQL for this

Basically, we take the distinct path expression, pivot them out, and select them using `FOR JSON PATH`

```sql
DECLARE @cols nvarchar(max) = (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(AttributePath),',')
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT AttributePath FROM EAV) EAV
);

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'
SELECT
    id = EntityID,
    ' + @cols + '
FROM EAV
PIVOT (
    MAX(AttributeValue) FOR AttributePath IN (
        ' + @cols + '
    )
) pvt
FOR JSON PATH;
';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

**Result**

```json
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "user":{
         "address":{
            "city":"Pittsburgh",
            "state":"Pennsylvania"
         },
         "firstName":"John",
         "lastName":"Doe"
      }
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "user":{
         "address":{
            "city":"Pittsburgh",
            "state":"Pennsylvania"
         },
         "firstName":"Jane",
         "lastName":"Doe"
      }
   }
]
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=006276873f385ad91eed57ac35e4f130)

Comment: This works great for my example! Unfortunately I oversimplified it and the real-life data includes, for example, array attributes whose multiple values are multiple rows in SQL (i.e. if person 1 had two firstName values, John and Jim, in separate rows with the same AttributePath). From my testing, the resulting JSON never gets a firstName collection object with multiple values... rather, it either only ends up with one of them, or it ends up creating multiple person 1 objects, each with subsets of attributes. Is there any way to work around that?

Comment: Not really, because duplicate keys are not to JSON specification. Most parsers will just pick the first one they come across. You could perhaps number them `FirstName1` `FirstName2` using `ROW_NUMBER` however that would be fairly complex and a new [so] question is warranted

Comment: [I tried a fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=61462a0dd2b7a8fe7a47970b05adb133) that utilized `STRING_AGG()` in the PIVOT, but I'm getting a syntax error... would something like that work?

`PIVOT (
    STRING_AGG(AttributeValue, '','') FOR AttributePath IN (
        ' + @cols + '
    )
) pvt
FOR JSON PATH;`

The end goal being to turn multiple values in to arrays: `['Jim','Joe']`

Comment: You are not allowed to use `PIVOT` with any expression, it has to be of the form `AggregateFunction(ActualColumnName)`. You could pre-aggregate it like this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c7954083c97448bdcc6329fc3895f52c